# How to display an error message over a field

Tags: python, django

I want to display an error message if the field is blank in Django administration. At the moment, I know how to bring ValidationError early in the page, but I need to get the message right above the blank field. How can this be done?

have not yet been able to find an answer.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    title_ru = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    ...

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class form(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
        model = models.Article

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(forms.ModelForm, self).clean()
        title_ru = cleaned_data['title_ru']
        if not title_ru:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Title ru")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

`forms.ValidationError("Title ru")` displays a message at the top of the page, but I need this message over the field

how to get the message out over the field Title_ru ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are raising a `ValidationError` in the `clean` method, you are seeing the error message on the top of the page. Raise the validation error in `clean_title_ru` instead

```
def clean_title_ru(self):
    title_ru = self.cleaned_data['title_ru']
    if not title_ru:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Title ru")

    return self.cleaned_data['title_ru']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick and simple answer =) Now I know how to do it, and also found in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to check value in clean_title_ru, but if you want to check multiple value you can do it what way:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(forms.ModelForm, self).clean()
    title_ru = cleaned_data['title_ru']
    if not title_ru:
        msg = u"error in Title ru"
        self._errors["title_ru"] = self.error_class([msg])

        # These fields are no longer valid. Remove them from the cleaned data.
        del cleaned_data["title_ru"]

    return self.cleaned_data
```